# How do we prove (intuitively is fine) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n}$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

From my Khan acad knowledge, we know that if $p>1$ it converges, otherwise it diverges.
Intuitively we can tell that $\frac{\ln (n)}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$ whenever $n >e$. To further argue that it should converge I tried graphing it to show that the series indeed cover a larger area than a harmonic series ($\frac{1}{n}$), which should in my head result in a convergence if anything:

[image]

and yet, khan acad answer key concludes that "Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ "diverges".

I even tried pulling up the $p$-series "rules", while it's not a power that is larger than $1$, it is a value larger than $\frac{1}{n}$ for sure.

[image]

What am I missing here? Is it because I shouldn't be using graphs, if so how do we prove it?... I'm unable to understand how they concluded "Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ it "diverges".

Here is their answer key:

[image]

Comment: Something seems not quite right with your intuition... The series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (1/n)$ is divergent (“infinite”), and you consider another sum $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (\ln(n)/n)$ which is *larger* (term by term), so *of course* that sum is divergent too!

Comment: If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n)/n$ covers a larger area than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ and you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n = \infty$, i.e. the series covers an infinite area, what can you say about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n)/n$?

Comment: I see, I labeled the graph and can see that clearer. Is graphing it out a good way to get an intuition? Or will there be sometimes where it'd be conflicting..?

Comment: ie. Is everything above the harmonic series function (red graph) divergent?

Comment: @nvs0000 Good to know: "proof" is the noun, "prove" is the verb. Also, if a series $\sum a_n$ satisfies $a_n \ge 1/n$ for $n>N$ with a fixed $N$, $\sum a_n$ is divergent. In your words, if the graph of the terms in your series is eventually above the harmonic one, the series will diverge.

Comment: What is $p$ in the first sentence?

Comment: @Gary, thank you. Is harmonic series the very limit of divergent? Such that $\frac{1}{n^{0.99999999}}$ is divergent and $\frac{1}{n^{1.0000001)}}$ is convergent? If so is this a trick you'd learn in college to graph and conclude instead of using all the series of tests? (Ie. Ratio, limit, direct comparison test..?) I did not go to a conventional college and am teaching myself, so would love some tips and tricks (as long as it isn't detrimental to my fundamentals)!

Comment: @nvs0000 I believe you will need one of the tests. Indeed the harmonic series is the barrier. The usual tests for the $p$-series are the integral and the Cauchy condensation tests. You may be interested in the Riemann zeta function, look it up.

Comment: @nvs0000 The problem is that you cannot plot the infinite domain of functions. Maybe it looks like $a_n<b_n$ but it is only true for $n<1000000000$ and you are unable to see it in your graph.

Comment: Derivative of x^n is n*x(n-1), derivative of x^(n+1) /(n+1) is x^n, therefore integral of x^n is x^(n+1) / (n+1).  Doesn’t work for n = -1. But integral of x^-0.999999 is x^0.000001 / 0.00001 which is divergent (veeery slowly) and integral of x^-1.000001 is x^-0.000001 / -0.000001 which converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we prove (intuitively is fine) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
> > \frac{\ln (n)}{n}$ diverges?
>
> I'm unable to understand how they concluded "Since
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
> > \frac{1}{n}$ it "diverges".

The course assumes that by this point one is aware that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges,so that any other series $a_k$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$  also diverges.

What can be more intuitive than $b_k$ is a divergent series, $a_k>b_k$ from some $k$ onwards implies that $b_k$ diverges.

Comment: thank you. Is harmonic series the very limit of divergent? Such that 10.99999999 is divergent and 11.0000001) is convergent? If so is this a trick you'd learn in college to graph and conclude instead of using all the series of tests? (Ie. Ratio, limit, direct comparison test..?) I did not go to a conventional college and am teaching myself, so would love some tips and tricks (as long as it isn't detrimental to my fundamentals)!

Comment: @nvs0000 : there is no exact line as such, for any given convergent or divergent series , one can make a series that is just more or less to remain convergent or divergent, I had seen some examples like $\frac{1}{n (\log \log \cdots \log n)^{\alpha}}$ that can be be made convergent or divergent. another example is the you can remove terms containing say 3 or 4, or anything but 0 from harmonic series and the result will converge e.g. take out $2, 12, 22, 32, \cdots$ terms and result converges. for tricks just browse the questions labeled sequences and series.

Comment: @jimjim .Suppose each $x_n> 0$ and suppose that $\sum_nx_n$ diverges. Take a strictly increasing sequence $(m_j)_{j\in\Bbb N}$ of members of $\Bbb N$ with $n_1=1$ such that $\sum_{n=m_j}^{-1+m_{(j+1)}}x_n>1$ for every $j.$ Let $y_n=x_n/j$ when $ m_j\le n\le -1+m_{j+1}.$ Then $\sum_ny_n$ diverges and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n/x_n=0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : Thank  you for the answer, what is the question?

Comment: @jimjim. The proposer asked you about the 'limit of divergent".  I wanted to show that in a sense there is no lower limit.

Answer (score 0):

Integral test. If $f:[1,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and if $f(x)$ is decreasing for all sufficiently large $x\in [1,\infty)$ then $\sum_{j=1}^nf(j)$ converges as $n\to\infty$ iff $\int_1^nf(x)dx$ converges as $n\to\infty$.

Proof: Take $2\le n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x\ge n_0.$ For $n_1,n_2\in \Bbb N$ with $n_0\le n_1\le n_2$ we have $$0\le \int_{-1+n_1}^{n_2}f(x)dx\le  \sum_{j=n_1}^{n_2}f(j)\le \int_{n_1}^{1+n_2}f(x)dx\le \sum_{j=-1+n_1}^{n_2}f(j).... QED.$$
For $f(x)=(\ln x)/x$ we have $f'(x)=(1-\ln x)/x^2<0$ for $x>e$. And for $n\ge 1$ we have $$\int_1^n f(x)dx=\int_1^n\frac {\ln x}{x}dx= \int_1^n(\ln x)d(\ln x)=\frac {1}{2}(\ln n)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

For instance by creative telescoping. You may easily realize that $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is half the derivative of $\log^2 x$, and

$$ \log^2(n+1)-\log^2(n) = (\log(n+1)+\log(n))\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)< 2\frac{\log(n+1)}{n}< 2\left(\frac{\log n}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right). $$

This leads to

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\log n}{n} > \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\log^2(n+1)-\log^2(n)\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k^2}>\frac{\log^2(N+1)}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}. $$

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of f(n) diverges, f(n) >=0, and g(n) >=f(n) then g(n) diverges. And that’s the case here.

Intuitive divergence of 1/n: Sum for n= 1 is 1. Sum for 2<=n<= 2 is 1/2. Sum for 3<=n<=4 is 2 values >= 1/4, so >= 1/2.  Sum for 5 <= n <= 8 is 4 values >= 1/8, so >= 1/2. Sum for 9 <= n <= 16 is 8 values >= 1/16, so >= 1/2. You keep adding up 1/2 so the sum diverges.

Intuitive divergence of ln n/ n: we have ln 3 >= ln 2, ln 5 >= 2 ln 2, ln 9 >= 3 ln 2, ln 17 >= 4 ln 2, so doing Ehe sum sums we add 0 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 2/2 + 3/2 + 4/2 etc, which diverges even faster.